# Name a predicate function that takes multiple objects

Tags: javascript, naming

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
function tokensOnSameLine(node1, node2) {
    return node1.line == node2.line;
}
```

What would the preferred name for this function be?  I've considered the following:

- `isTokensOnSameLine` - sounds awkward but it matches the `is` convention for predicates.
- `areTokensOnSameLine` - sounds good, seems reasonably clear.
- `tokensOnSameLine` - okay, doesn't seem as obvious that it returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When naming a function, consider how it appears to the reader when they come across it in code.

For example;

```
if (tokensOnSameLine(node1, node2)) { ... }
if (isTokensOnSameLine(node1, node2)) { ... }
if (areTokensOnSameLine(node1, node2)) { ... }
```

Given that, I'd probably go with `tokensAreOnSameLine`

```
if (tokensAreOnSameLine(node1, node2)) { ... }
```